# Stack associated to Groupoid object in category $\text{Sch}/S$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks, grothendieck-topology, differentiable-stacks

Consider the category of manifolds $\text{Man}$.

A groupoid object in the category of manifolds is called a Lie groupoid, denoted by $\mathcal{G}$. There is a way to associate a stack (over the category $\text{Man}$) for this $\mathcal{G}$, the stack of principal $\mathcal{G}$ bundles, denoted by $B\mathcal{G}$. Any stack which is isomorphic to $B\mathcal{G}$ is called a geometric stack. So, geometric stacks are same as Lie groupoids; the **”geometric” stacks of interest over the category of manifolds** are precisely the **stacks associated to groupoid objects in the category of manifolds**.

Now, fix a scheme $S$ and consider the category, $\text{Sch}/S$, of schemes over $S$. Fix some Grothendieck topology (I do not know many, so, you can fix what ever is comfortable). In this category also I can talk about groupoid objects, take one such and denote by $\mathcal{G}$. Is there a way to associate a stack over the category $\text{Sch}/S$.

Is it the case, similar to the case of manifolds, that the **”geometric” stacks of interest over the category $\text{Sch}/S$** are precisely the **stacks associated to groupoid objects in the category of $\text{Sch}/S$**? I mean to ask are Algebraic stack precisely the stacks coming from groupoid object in category $\text{Sch}/S$? I guess the answer is No (please feel free to add some comments regarding this).

Are stacks over $\text{Sch}/S$ associated to groupoids over $\text{Sch}/S$ of any interest? Do they cover “most” of Algebraic stacks over the stack $S$ with what ever topology on $\text{Sch}/S$? Are there (basic) examples of stacks associated to groupoids over $\text{Sch}/S$ that are not algebraic?

Comment: Just after reading the title I *knew* it was a question by you! :-)  If you allow your "geometric" groupoids to be internal to **algebraic spaces** instead of just schemes, and consider the *lisse* (smooth) topology, then I think all the answers become "yes" by Laumon--Moret-Bailly *Champs algébriques*, (4.3) and Proposition (4.3.1).

Comment: @Qfwfq I am taking “Just after reading the title I knew it was a question by you!” as a nice comment, not sure if this was supposed to be nice :D.. Can you please give some English reference... Does it follow as straight forward as in the case of Lie groupoids or it is more serious (I do not think there is no definite answer for this, just asking)...

Comment: "I am taking [...]" No offence intended! - You could have a look at the Stacks Project; looks like there's a whole chapter on groupoids in algebraic spaces (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0437). The association groupoid in alg sp $\mapsto$ corresponding stack is (I think) https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/044O. For the reverse association, I think you just take the groupoid $U\times_{\mathscr{X}}U\to U$ of an atlas $U\to\mathscr{X}$.

Comment: @Qfwfq I knew no offence was intended :) :) I saw that chapter of groupoids on Algebriac spaces just now.. it looks good, I will see what I can understand from that... I will also read about quotient stacks as well.

Comment: Probably all you need is buried somewhere in sections 16 and 17 here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/algebraic.pdf#nameddest=04T0. Also: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06PI

Comment: It does say a way to associate a Algebraic stack for a groupoid over Algebriac spaces and also says how to associate a algebraic space for a Algebriac stack... I do not see if it is saying something about “Do they cover “most” of Algebriac stacks over the stack  with what ever topology on $\text{Sch}/S$“

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. Unless I'm disregarding some subtleties (e.g. conditions on the diagonal etc), if you start with an alg stack $X$, which by definition has an atlas $U\to X$ with $U$ an alg space, you can form a groupoid $U\times_X U\rightrightarrows U$, internal to algebraic spaces, whose associated stack (a.k.a. quotient stack) is isomorphic to $X$. Viceversa, given a groupoid $X_1\rightrightarrows X_0$ in alg sp, satisfying certain conditions, the quotient stack $[X_0/X_1]$ will have an atlas $X_0\to [X_1/X_0]$ making it (if the conditions are ok) an alg stack.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just copied the statement from the question, which intended to ask, if I take groupoid internal to schemes, to what extent the corresponding stack is away from being an algebraic stack.. I have no trouble understanding (believing) algebraic spaces and algebraic stacks correspondence as in your comment, it was not my question, sorry to make you type that much for no reason.

Comment: Well, also a mere groupoid internal to manifolds will not be a *Lie* groupoid in general: you need the source and target maps be submersions (and maybe some further topological condition?). For the algebraic case you have conditions such as source and target being smooth (in the sense of alg geom) and other stuff.

Comment: As for "how far" you can get without making these requirements, that's a question you should clarify better. E.g. are you looking for an explicit example of a grpd internal to schemes (or alg sp) whose quot stack is not algebraic? (BTW, I think the schemes vs alg spaces thing is orthogonal to these matters)

Comment: @Qfwfq "a mere groupoid internal to manifolds will not be a Lie groupoid in general".. Is that so :O I think it is a Lie groupoid, some time back I have written details, not sure where it is now... I am nore sure how to clarify the question, I tried to write down as clearly as I can.. I agree there is some confusion... I did not get "schemes vs alg spaces thing is orthogonal to these matters".. Can you please clarify

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_groupoid -- As for the second aspect, the answer by S. Carnahan below shows you don't actually need algebraic spaces (for this).

Comment: @Qfwfq  I do not see anything about (being internal) in that in Wikipedia page... nlab says it is internal https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+groupoid... I see the comment, “Note that Diff does not have all pullbacks, but by suitable conditions on the source and target map we can ensure that the requisite pullbacks do exist.” So, what you mentioned is correct in some sense, groupoid object (with appropriate changes) is Lie groupoid and this is what I had in mind when I said internal groupoid (with appropriate changes).

Comment: As a general reference, these notes seem to me to be good, especially Appendix C: https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.08124

Comment: I saw that notes just now. It seems to be giving some answer to my question. I will read that and respond...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any algebraic stack $X$, there is a groupoid in schemes whose fppf stackification is equivalent to $X$.  You can construct such a groupoid following the stacks project, by choosing a smooth presentation in algebraic spaces ([Lemma 04T5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04T5)), then choosing an étale presentation of the component algebraic spaces ([Lemma 0262](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0262)).

There are stacks associated to groupoids in schemes that are not algebraic.  For example, the classifying stack of an infinite type affine group scheme over a field is not algebraic, by [Lemma 04AH](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04AH).

Comment: Ok, I am not sure if I am understanding correctly or not.. For an algebriac stack $X$, we some how get a  groupoid in scheme... For this groupoid,  we associate a stack (in the usual sense we associate stack for Lie groupoid) over some Grothendieck topology... But, this is **not a stack with respect to the fppf topology**... so, we stackify (tag/06WP) to get a stack/fppf... Then, this stack is isomorphic to $X$.. Is this correct?

Comment: I will try to understand those lemmas and ask specific questions, if I have any. Thanks.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik The point is that quotients behave badly with respect to gluing, so from a groupoid you just get a fibered category (or equivalently, functor to groupoids) with no guarantees about effectiveness of descent.  The same problem holds even without the complications of groupoids, when you consider quotient sheaves of sets - you first get a quotient presheaf, then you sheafify.