# Why not consider categorical quotient in stacks?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks

Let's say we have a $k$ group scheme $G$ acting on a $k$ scheme $X$, we can consider its quotient in the category of stacks, the usual definition of it would be the quotient stack $[X/G]$ defined by

> $[X/G](S)$ is the groupoid of $G$ bundles over $S$ together an equivariant maps to $X$.

My **Question 1** is why don't we take the categorical quotient?

I think the categorical quotient exists because we can take the categorical quotient in the categories of 2-functors from Schemes to Groupoids, and then sheafify (stackify).

I understand that the stack quotients enjoy some very good properties, e.g. it makes every action look like a free action and it the theory of sheaves downstair is equivalent to the theory of sheaves.

but why people (or do they) don't study categorical quotient as well?

My **Question 2** is how do stack quotients differentiate from categorical quotients?

Stack quotient is equal to the categorical quotient in the case free action, and I have the feeling that the two notions agree only when the action is free, is it true?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly.. You say "Schemes to Groupoids, and then sheafify (stackify)"... I thought this is what happening.. Isn't it so?  See page 29 for definition of $\widetilde{y}(\mathcal{G})$ for a Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ and page number 69 how sheafification/stackification comes into picture when defining the stack $B\mathcal{G}$... This is about stacks coming from Lie groupoids.. I am sure the same can be done for stacks coming through schemes...

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/a/339953/118688 It looks like it holds for schemes as well

Comment: answer in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319038/motivation-for-definition-of-quotient-stack may be of useful..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, I am sorry, I should be more clear. I always think about stacks coming from schemes. What I mean is thinking a stack as a (pseduo) functor from the categories of schemes to the categories of groupoids. We can take categorical quotient in this larger category, and the stackification of it is the categorical quotient in the category of stacks. My question is that why people don't care about categorical quotient stack even they always exist.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for a map from $X$ to a stack that is $G$-invariant and universal with respect to $G$-invariant maps to stacks.  The quotient map $X \to [X/G]$ satisfies this property, so stack quotients and categorical quotients in stacks are the same thing.

Comment: I do not think I still understand it... Lets wait for some one more experienced to comment...

Comment: @S.Carnahan I think the categorical quotient should be universal with respect to $G$ invariant maps FROM $X$. A simple example to see the two concepts are different is the case of the trivial action acting on point, the stack quotient is $BG$, and categorical quotient is just the point.

Comment: You seem to be working with some sort of 1-category of stacks. I'm unclear on how exactly it is defined, but regardless that is not the right thing to consider. What you want to consider is the (2,1)-category of stacks, and there $BG$ *is* the categorical quotient. In general any notion that does not identify two equivalent stacks is unlikely to have geometric meaning.